# DataBase not updating in C# when using service-based database

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm trying to write a program for my exam. I have to use and work with database, i've written some code and encountered a problem. Database is not updating. When I execute my application everything works perfectly, I add some info and it appears in my dataGridView, but when I go to the table in database that i've been updating and select "Show table data", it's empty.

This is function that inserts data into my database.

```
static public void Insert(string _imonesPav, string _imonesKodas, string _sutartiesPradzia, string _sutartiesPabaiga)
   {
       try 
       {
           connection.Open();
           SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Tiekejai VALUES (@ImonesPav, @ImonesKodas, @SutartiesPradzia, @SutartiesPabaiga)", connection);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImonesPav", _imonesPav);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImonesKodas", _imonesKodas);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutartiesPradzia", _sutartiesPradzia);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutartiesPabaiga", _sutartiesPabaiga);
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       catch (SqlException exception)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
       }
       finally
       {
           connection.Close();
       }
   }
```

And this is how i use it.

```
private void updateDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            SQLFunkcijos.Insert(imonesVardas.Text, imonesKodas.Text, sutartPradzia.Text, sutartPabaiga.Text);
            SQLFunkcijos.Refresh(this.dataGridView1);
    }
```

Refresh function is used to update data in dataGridView in real time.
So the question would be, what am i doing wrnog? Why table in database is not updating.
P.S. I've tried all Copy to Output options, it works only with Copy if newer.

EDIT1: Refersh function.

```
static public void Refresh(DataGridView _dataGridView)
   {
       try
       {
           connection.Open();
           SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM Tiekejai", connection);
           DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
           dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
           _dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
       }
       catch(SqlException exception)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
       }
       finally
       {
           connection.Close();
       }
   }
```

EDIT2: Problem solved! I was just using bad connection string. Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: What is `SQLFunckcijos` is that a datagrid. can you explain also what are you not using the standard `Insert INTO (Table Name Columns, Values)` syntax..? I am confused if you say it works properly but when you do a Select statement it's not returning data.. can you verify that the values have been updated.. ? perhaps `MySql` requires an explicit `Commit` to be invoked.. what does this actually do `SQLFunkcijos.Refresh(this.dataGridView1);` is this a method if so show it's code..

Comment: Another clarification. You use the class SqlCommand but you have tagged your question with `MySql`. Could you clarify if you are using Sql Server or MySql?

Comment: are you calling DataBind() after assigning the DataSource.. please show the Refresh method too

Comment: @Steve sorry for confusing you, I'm using Microsoft SQL Server with Visual Studio Express 2013

Comment: @MethodMan `SQLFunkcijos` is a class which contains all of my functions. I meant not select statement but option in server explorer when you left click table and press "Show table data" and its empty here.

Comment: @MethodMan The DataGridView is a Winforms control, so there is no DataBind() method.

Comment: @Martin you do not need to call the `.Open()` when using `DataAdapter`

Comment: `dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);` when you put a break point after this line and use the `QuickWatch hitting the magnifying glass` do you see any data populated when you inspect `dataTable`

Comment: @MethodMan you mean Data table visualizer?

Comment: yes this will work also

Comment: @MethodMan it shows that it's empty

Comment: well there you have it.. you're query is not returning records.. which means there is something wrong with the Select statement and or your connection to the database make sure you are selecting from the proper table

Comment: @MethodMan it shows everything perfectly while app is running, but it doesn't apply any changes to real database. Thats the problem.

Comment: for starters you should create either a stored procedure to handle your INSERTS as well as Change your Insert statement to Insert Into the Table the Columns you want Values() that go into those columns

Comment: @MethodMan Probelm solved. I was just using bad connection string. Still thanks for your time.

Comment: exactly what I mentioned wow you wasted a lot of time next time start using the debugger glad you figured out your own problem